# "No supported authentication methods available" when connecting to gcloud with FileZilla

Tags: sftp, filezilla, google-compute-engine

I've followed this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/lamp/transfer-files

I have my private key generated and added to FileZilla but I can't seem to connect.

The guide specifies to insert `sftp://instanceip` but FileZilla keeps stripping out the `sftp://` - could this be the problem?

The error in FileZilla says:

> Error:    Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
>   Error:    Could not connect to server

Comment: Please include FileZilla log. Ideally also server-side log. And no, it's not related to "sftp://" being stripped.

Comment: Did you add the public key to your instance(s) via [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/console#sshkeys)? An easy way to add the ssh keys is to also use [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) to connect to the VM which will transfer the public key for you.